# Memory leak messages in MonoTouch - do I have to deal with these?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios

I'm used to ASP.NET which has a garbage collector. However after getting into MonoTouch and iPhone programming I find many of these messages when running my app.

Do I ignore them, or should I implement some sort of unload method in each viewcontroller to dispose of objects?

Is this the kind of things that the Apple guys will be looking at when I submit my app to iTunes (I've yet to do this)?

```
2011-02-12 20:58:55.641 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfd34dd0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.648 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfd3a710 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.649 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfd3a830 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.650 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfd3bae0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.651 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce8a520 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.651 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce8a5e0 of class NSPathStore2 autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.658 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7bccd40 of class __NSArrayReverseEnumerator autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.659 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7bce550 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.659 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7bce550 of class __NSArrayI autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.660 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce8f280 of class NSIndexPath autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.664 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce90480 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.664 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce90690 of class UICFFont autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.670 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce91c30 of class NSIndexPath autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.671 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xfd3a840 of class NSIndexPath autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.673 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x7bcc550 of class CAlertView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.674 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce91ca0 of class __NSArrayM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.675 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x6e87c10 of class _UIAlertOverlayWindow autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.675 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce90a50 of class UIInputViewSet autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.676 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce90a60 of class UIInputViewAnimationStyle autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.676 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce93bf0 of class CABasicAnimation autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.677 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce93c00 of class NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
2011-02-12 20:58:55.677 wps[1200:7803] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xce93a10 of class __NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating NSObjects on an explicitly created (non-threadpool) thread.  You must wrap the thread in

```
using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {
  // thread work goes here
}
```

Comment: Hi,  
So would I put all my code in there see below for what I am doing on viewdidappear
or put my loadPageDetailsThread code in between the using claus?


private void loadPageDetails() {

   spinner = new Spinner();

   spinner.Message ="Please wait...";  

   spinner.SpinnerType =  SpinnerType.ActivityIndicator;

   spinner.Show();

   ThreadStart job = new ThreadStart(loadPageDetailsThread);
              
   Thread SpinnerThread = new Thread(job);

         SpinnerThread.Start(); 

  }

  
  public void loadPageDetailsThread() {

   //Do something 
 
   spinner.Hide(true); 

  }